# Magento 2: limit staging emails to dev only

Tags: magento2, email, staging

Just realized that our staging environment is sending out emails to customers, which is not good.

How can I limit the emails to developers only? Ideally I would like to:

- provide a list of allowed emails
- provide a default email to which all emails not in "allowed" list would be 
  routed to

Already did a google search and didn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: I think database cleanup would help you out if that is okay to you.. Remove all the live customers data from staging environment.

Comment: That is an idea, but since we do regularly re-create staging from live, would prefer an extension which I can config it based on our needs.

Answer (score 0):

We can't limit the emails like you asked. But we can disable the Email functionality itself in the Staging or DEV environment by following the below steps.

**Step 1:** Go to **Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> System -> Advanced**.

**Step 2:** Set **Mail Sending Settings** to **Yes** to disable the Email functionality.

Reference link: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/email-communications.html

Mailtrap is also an option. So the actual users will not receive the mails But we can review them.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I no longer work with Magento, but I am sure someone else will find your answer useful. But do note that back in the day, I reverted into cleaning the database for staging and then adding fake users. Today, I would look into sending emails to Mailtrap or related service. I am sure that someone already coded extension for this.

Comment: Sure @KristjanO. I had also included the MailTrap in my answer. Thanks !!